# logging back in always freezing after 22.04 installation

Tags: login, 22.04, freeze

Fresh installation of 22.04. Got things almost completely set up the way I like, however, I'm finding that, when I log out, I get to my login screen, as expected. When I put in my password and hit 'enter', though, the screen freezes. This happens every time.

After living with this for some time, I started to investigate and found that, if I finish typing my password and hit 'enter', if I let the frozen screen sit for a long time, it eventually goes to a black screen.

Somewhere I read about hitting ctl-alt-f1, followed by ct-alt-f2, so I tried that. That does take me to a cli login where I am actually able to log in.

Once logged into this cli environment, I tried 'startx.' That fails and I'm stuck having to reboot.

Is this known? Is there a solution? Or, do I just have to reboot instead of logging out/in.

thanks,
babag

Comment: After `ctl-alt-f1` check for the latest things added to `dmesg | less` and add any info you find relevant to your text above (note: `edit`)

Answer (score 0):

May have fixed this issue. Changed my command from:

```
killall -u babag
```

to:

```
qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 0 3
```

This was an issue with a desktop icon shortcut I use to logout. I decided to try logging out from another source, in this case the KDE Aplication Launcher on the taskbar. In fact, it behaved normally, no freeze. Under the assumption that the launcher might be using a different command to log out, that started me searching for other commands, which produced the above solution.

I've used the killall method going back, possibly, as far as Kubuntu 16 and, definitely, on 20. It never gave me a problem. The switch to 22.04 seems to have brought a change, though.

Thanks for the response, Hannu.